# Using gdf file with netlogo nw extension

Tags: netlogo

I have successfully loaded a gdf file using the nw extension in NetLogo.
How can I limit the number of turtles?
Attached the code I wrote:

```
exextensions [ nw ]
breed [ orgs org ]
directed-link-breed [ likes like ]
to setup
  ca
  nw:load-gdf "d://netlogoWork/j14clean.gdf"  orgs likes 
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "limit the number of turtles"? That code will create as many turtles as there are nodes in the gdf file.

Comment: I would like to control the number of turtles within NetLogo itself.

Comment: The gdf defines a certain number of nodes, though. If you want NetLogo to limit the number of turtles, you can kill some of the turtles after they're created.